# how to cancel all ajax request inside for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

how to cancel all ajax request that handled by for loop

```
var url = ["www.example.com","www.example2.com",....];

for (var i = 0; i < url.length; i++) {

var XHR =$.get(url[i], function(data) {
    //stuff to do 

});
}
```

tried to use

```
XHR.abort()
```

but it cancel last loop only

Comment: Try to put your requests in an array. Something like this `var arrXhr=[]; ... var xhr = $.get(...); arrXhr.push(xhr);`. Then `arrXhr[index].abort();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It stops only the last request because you're assigning the reference of the AJAX calls repeatedly in the `for` loop. So when the loop ends, you will end up having the reference of last AJAX call in `XHR` variable.

Calling `abort()` on `XHR` will only stop the last request. To mitigate, you need to put all your AJAX requests in a second array, and loop on it to stop each request:

```
var url = ["www.example.com","www.example2.com",....];
// Create a second array to hold the references of AJAX requests
var requests = [];

for (var i = 0; i < url.length; i++) {
  var XHR = $.get(url[i], function(data) {
    // do stuff here
  });

  // Add the AJAX reference to the array
  requests.push(XHR);
}

// To stop all requests:
requests.forEach(request => request.abort());
```

Answer (score 1):

You should store the reference of all the ajax request in an array instead of storing it in a single variable.

```
var url = ["www.example.com","www.example2.com",....];
var xhr_all = [];

for (var i = 0; i < url.length; i++) {

var XHR =$.get(url[i], function(data) {
    //stuff to do 

});

xhr_all.push(XHR);
}
```

NOW loop through all the elements of xhr_all variable to abort all the ajax request.

```
for (var i = 0; i < xhr_all.length; i++) {
    xhr_all[i].abort();
}
```